# Is there a way to prevent coupling between unit tests and tested classes

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, tdd

I have been using unit tests for quite a while. And I have a concern.

Assume I have an interface and one implementation

```
public interface UserDAO() {
     public User getById(int id);
}

public class UserDAOJdbc implements UserDAO {
     private CoolDataSource datasource; //Dependency injection
     public User getById(int id) {
        User user = this.dataSource.executeSQL("SELECT ....")
        return user;
     }
}
```

It is fairly easy to test UserDAOJdbc, just need to inject the dataSource object and replace it with a mock, the problem however is

- This makes it difficult to write first the test and then the implementation, as before having the implementation I do not know how a particular UserDAO implementation is gonna work.
- It makes test and implementation completely coupled, I am not sure if this is avoidable at all, but does not feel good.
- In the case of an object that uses several objects to accomplish a task, mocking it becames a little bit harder, not to speak about changes.

Is there an effective way to prevent this? Is mocking a bad approach for some scenarios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A unit test always tests an implementation. There's no point in testing interfaces. If you have more than one implementation of `UserDAO` you need to write more than one test.

Comment: That is how I work, a test per implementation, the problem is that each test is highly coupled with its implementation and specially I have no effective way to predict which objects a particular implementation will be composed of. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I would respectfully disagree with BetaRide and suggest to **test against interfaces**. Different classes implementing the **same interface** would have the same functionality signature, implemented in a different way.

- Therefore, you could write the whole test before implementation. This makes [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) evitable.
- The tests would be abstract enough to be reused for other interface implementations. You could achieve reusability but that also depends on your testing framework.
- You would have a more maintainable test code base
- This would lead you to a better design. This is a subjective conclusion but it is my opinion that you are forced to make a more generic design when you write tests against interfaces before writing the actual implementation.

For example, lets suppose that you have an `IRepository` interface and two implementations `DatabaseRepository` and `FilesRepository` which implement the `IRepository`. If you test against the `IRepository` , this test could be **reused** among both `FilesRepository` and `DatabaseRepository` implementations. Moreover, the test could be written by the programmer writing the interface, **before** any of the implementation classes ready.

Hope I helped!

Comment: I cannot see how it is effective to test against interfaces, different implementations can be really different, maybe they are composed of different objects, also do not assume that the datasource is always a database, and well, maybe a DAO could even have two datasources in certain implementations.

Answer (score 0):

In case of unit testing the DAO you can use a Derby or some other small database that can embed into your application. You can actually create an entity manager factory and keep it ready in the setup method. The other methods can use it. Its not a pure unit test but helps you test easily.

Comment: Forget about the DAO scenario, imagine testing Services for example. The problem for me is not the database, the problem is how to effectively predict how an implementation will be composed.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to go about your problem :

- Develop your application from the outside in. Imagine the dependencies your current object under test needs, but don't create concrete implementations for them yet. Just reason about operations and create interfaces with the appropriate method signatures. Mock these interfaces in your test.
- Once the test passes, pick one of these interfaces. Create an abstract base test class and put general tests for all future implementations of the interface there. This is the contract of your interface, that all implementors must respect. For instance :

```java
// High level, implementation-decoupled contract test
public abstract class UserDAOTest {

  protected abstract UserDAO getSut();
  protected abstract void insertUser(User user);

  @Test
  public void userFoundReturnsUser() {
    User expectedUser = new User(1);
    insertUser(expectedUser);

    assertEquals(expectedUser, getSut().getById(1));
  }

  @Test
  public void userNotFoundReturnsNull() {
    assertNull(getSut().getById(123));
  }

  @Test (expected=Exception.class)
  public void negativeIdthrowsException() {
    GetSut().getById(-2);
  }

}
```

- Create as many test subclasses as you need implementations of the interface in your system. In each one, override the abstract test utility methods defined above to provide implementation-specific details. JUnit and other test frameworks will automatically run all tests from the base class for each derivative. Add any implementation-specific tests you may want.
- Implement the concrete class, making the tests pass.
- Jump to the next interface. Repeat.